# No DEBUG messages on stdout/stderr

Tags: ros, roscpp, rosconsole, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When printing/logging messages with `ROS_DEBUG` there is no output on *stdout*/*stderr*, despite launching a node with `output="screen"`. On the other hand, `ROS_INFO`, `ROS_WARN` and `ROS_ERROR` (along with their variants) work as intended, printing the message to the console.

Looking into [ROS logging documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging), debug messages should be printed by default, while warning and error message *shouldn't*. In additions, nothing is printed to logfiles.

How do I go about fixing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405642/no-debug-messages-on-stdout/stderr/) by [joaocandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/44860/joaocandre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> debug messages should be printed by default, while warning and error message shouldn't.

could you clarify what makes you conclude this? Preferably using a quote from the page you link?

The *Output* section mentions that everything only ends up on `stdout` and `stderr` "*if they are enabled*" (the log levels that is, not `stdout` or `stderr`).

The default log level is `INFO`, not `DEBUG` (end of the [Log Statements](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging#Log_Statements) section):

> The default verbosity level is `INFO`, so `DEBUG` statements will not be seen by default.

For `DEBUG` messages to be logged, you'll have to change the debug level of the logger that's emitting them. You could do that using a `.conf` file loaded by  your `.launch` ([wiki/rosconsole: Configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1